# To retrieve json data in jquery request succeeds

Tags: php, jquery, json, types

I have a little funny problem:

I get json data like this:

```
{"answer0":"IMG_0793.JPG not allowed file size","answer1":"sajty-mira.jpg uploaded","answer2":"\u0433
\u0432\u0441.txt unsupported File type"}
```

using jquery $.ajax

here I have

```
success: function(resp)
{
var numFiles = $("#file").get(0).files.length;

for(i=0; i < numFiles; i++){
var answ = "resp.answer"+i;
$('#response').append(answ).css('color', 'black').html('<br>');
}
}
```

to show each upload status.
So can't make resp.answer0,resp.answer1,resp.answer2 ...

```
var answ = "resp.answer"+i; not working!
```

I can do this with php

```
<?php 
for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; $i++){
echo"
$('#response').append(resp.answer".$i.").css('color', 'black').append('<br>');
";
}
?>
```

please help to solve the problem!

Comment: I think you are erroneously mixing server side and client side logic.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `append()` this way (just appending a string):

```
$('#response').append(answ).css('color', 'black').html('<br>');
```

Inside append should have a valid html tag:

```
$('#response').append('<div>' + answ + '</div>').css('color', 'black').html('<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse json response using

```
var response = $.parseJSON(resp);
```

Than you can use response variable.

Comment: Like this? var response = $.parseJSON(resp);
for(i=0; i < numFiles; i++){
var answ = "response.answer"+i;
$('#response').append('<div>' + answ + '</div>').css('color', 'black').html('<br>');
}   not working

Comment: var answer = response.answer + i; $('#response').append(answer).css('color', 'black').append('<br>');

Comment: Just try a `console.log(response)` before & after parsing the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the eval() function

Like below:

```
resp = {"answer0":"IMG_0793.JPG not allowed file size","answer1":"sajty-mira.jpg uploaded","answer2":"\u0433\u0432\u0441.txt unsupported File type"}
var i = 1;
var answ = eval("resp.answer"+i);
console.log('answ:'+answ); // This will print answ:sajty-mira.jpg uploaded
```

Comment: They don't allow me to vote! Requires 15 reputation!

Comment: You should avoid to use eval for somthing coming from outside, it opens XSS vulnerabilities

Comment: @alexis , agree with you, but here the input is not coming from outside instead it is the resultant json. eval can be used based on the situation where you are intending to use it. But yes avoid using to process on any posted value etc